# MySQL + Hibernate Update queries are not executed

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I have a mysql 5 DB and a hibernate 4 appication

I use this method to update a certain entity

```
public void executeNamedQuery(String namedQuery,Map params) {
    if(params != null){
        try{
            getSession().getNamedQuery(namedQuery).setProperties(params).executeUpdate();
            getSession().flush();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else{
        getSession().getNamedQuery(namedQuery).executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

and this is what the debugger writes

```
Hibernate: update announcement set status=?, dcp_id=? where announcement_id=?
```

and when I open mysql log table I find this query in the queries that came in

```
update announcement set status=-6, dcp_id=149714 where announcement_id=81
```

but the row is not updated, and when I do it in workbench it works fine.

what could be causing the problem here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don´t know whats around `executeNamedQuery`, but it seems that your changes are not committed to the database. In that case the upate will be rolled back after transaction timeout.